# How to detect if is subpage in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want to make a check if im on a subpage. On the homepage it is :

`<?php if(is_front_page()): ?> <?php endif; ?>`

But how to do it when it is another page?

Comment: `if (! is_front_page() )`, i guess this is not an answer to what you want but it is literally the answer to your question.

Comment: Your right. I need to know how to check a specific page..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page):

> There is no function to check if a page is a sub-page. We can get around the problem:

```
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0 ) { 
    echo "This is a child page";
}
```